# mlt add audio tracks to multitrack audio without mixing

Tags: mlt

I have 2 separate stereo wav files, and I want to create a wav file with the 2 stereo tracks but without mixing them. So that the left channel of file 1 would be mapped to the left channel of track 1 of the multitrack file, etc.
How can you do this with melt?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you want 4 audio tracks in the output file? Two from the first file and two from the second file? Or, do you want "file1 left" to be the left output and "file2 right" to be the right output file?

Answer (score 0):

Just as you first said, 4 audio tracks in the output file.Two from the first file and two from the second file.